# Count number of lines in each directory

Tags: unix, awk, xargs, wc

I have a directory structure as below

> output/a/1/multipleFiles
>    output/a/2/multipleFiles
>   output/a/3/multipleFiles
>    output/b/1/multipleFiles
>   output/b/2/multipleFiles
>    output/b/3/multipleFiles

I want to know number of lines each directory has. So basically, number of lines at each inner most directory level instead of file level. The innermost directories 1, 2, 3 are different kinds of output we generate for our analytics which contains multiple hadoop part-xxxx files.

I moved to output directory and tried the below command.

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '*' | awk -F "/" 'NF==3' | awk '{print $0"/*"}' | xargs wc -l
```

But I am getting an error as

```
wc: ./a/1/*: No such file or directory
wc: ./a/2/*: No such file or directory
wc: ./a/3/*: No such file or directory
```

but if I try

```
wc -l ./a/1/*
```

I am getting correct output for that specific folder.

What am I missing here.

EDIT:

I updated my command as below to remove unnecessary awk commands.

```
 find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '*'  | xargs wc -l
```

This again results in error as

```
wc: ./a/1: Is a directory 
wc: ./a/2: Is a directory 
wc: ./a/2: Is a directory
```

Comment: `.a/1/*` is different than `./a/1/*` (the slash after `.`)... could you explain the purpose of awk command on find's output? would `-mindepth` not help?

Comment: glob wildcard chars such as `*` are interpreted as-is by xargs without expansion --- hence the error you're seeing.

Comment: Are you trying to sum the number of lines within all files in each directory, or are you trying to count the number of files in each directory or the number of files and directories in each directory or something else? Please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output to clarify what you're trying to do as right now all we have to try to figure out what you want to do is a script that does not do whatever it is you want to do!

Comment: @EdMorton: Each innermost sub directory is a output of some analytic we generate, this innermost directory has multiple hadoop part-xxxx files, so I need to count the number of records each analytic populated and need to send that value for further validation.

Comment: @Sundeep: updated my qsn, thanks for that. The purpose of awk after find is, when I run find it list all the directories and sub directories. 
Yes -mindepth would help to exclude uppermost directories.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to `execdir`, for example:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -execdir wc -l {} \;
```

This will run the command `wc -l {}` only within the directory that the file has been found, from the man:

```
 -execdir The -execdir primary is identical to the -exec primary with 
          the exception that utility will be executed from the 
          directory that holds the current file.
```

Comment: find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 3 -type f -execdir wc -l {} \;
This works partially but provides count for each value. Is there any way I can I get count for the whole directory, but not for individual file.

Comment: @Abhinay probably piping the output to awk, for example: `| awk '{sum +=$1} END { print sum}'`